# how i can add Add text at the beginning of each line?

Tags: linux, command-line-interface, files

how i can add Add text at the beginning of each line?

for example:-
i have file contain:-
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/fees
/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/2ds

i want it to become:-

svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/core
svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/fees
svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo/var/lib/svn/repos/b1me/products/payone/generic/code/2ds

in other word i want to add "svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo" at the beginning of each line of this file

Comment: to get this to work you are going to have to add an `svn` command to the beginning of each line too e.g. `svn list svn+ssh://svn.xx.com.jo/var ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your text is a file named "file.txt" you use this command line

```
awk '{print "svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo" $1}' file.txt
```

It will output what you want. (assuming that no path contain a space)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Vim in Ex mode:

```sh
ex -sc '%s,^,svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo,|x' filename
```

1. `%` select all lines
2. `s` substitute
3. `x` save and close

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's|^|svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo|' filename
```

To change the file in place:

```
sed -i 's|^|svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo|' filename
```

Comment: i execute it but the following error apear.....command garbled:

Comment: Your version of `sed` may need `-e`: `sed -e 's|^|svn+ssh://svn.xxx.com.jo|' filename`